# Complie latest lighttpd for Debian Stretch by hand

Tags: compilation, debian, lighttpd

On my Debian stretch server I have lighttpd 1.4.45. I understand, that  it takes some time to prepare a package. However I would likely need some of the bug fixes in the latest version of lighttpd (1.4.49).

Which means basically, that I am left with either compiling lighttpd myself, or upgrading to a newer Debian (I think Buster), which is in testing phase.

So basically I need help, compiling lighttpd.

**So far, what I have got:**

1. Download tar package in user folder and untar it.

   sudo wget http://lighttpd.net/download/lighttpd-1.4.49.tar.gz

   sudo tar -zxvf lighttpd-1.4.49.tar.gz

   cd lighttpd-1.4.49

Now obviously my questions are:

1. How do I compile this, there is a make-sh script and also a Complie in the dir.
2. After compilation how do I move the compiled demon to /etc/lighttpd
3. How do I use the config files I am already using?

**EDIT:**

1. After I went to the dir i tried the following command

   ./configure

this did something, then I tried:

```
make
```

that inputed: make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

but I can see in the dir Makefile.am and Makefile.in

Answer (score 1):

the tarball comes with a few files which you might find an interesting read:

#### `INSTALL`

which contains

```
$ cd lighttpd-1.x.x
$ ./configure
$ make
$ su -
# make install
# exit
```

#### `README`

> ### ----------------- Starting lighttpd
>
> As daemon in the background: ::
>
> ```
> $ lighttpd -f <configfile>
> ```
>
> or without detaching from the console: ::
>
> ```
> $ lighttpd -D -f <configfile>
> ```

Comment: I read the INSTALL file in the tarbal, as I pointed out I tried out the sequence described  in it. ANd the result is that " make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop.".
I am not  where I am making an error.

Comment: most likely in the `./configure [...] did something`  step. *what* did it do? did it complain? running `./configure` should create `Makefile`s and it does so on my system, so something went wrong beforehand.

Comment: ./configure --without-pcre --without-zlib --without-bzip2

I was forced to use this in order for the configure to generate the necessary filed. Then I run just "make" it did something with output like this: 
Making install in tests
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/ivan/lighttpd-1.4.49/tests'
Making install in docroot
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ivan/lighttpd-1.4.49/tests/docroot'

I typed "servce lighttpd restart" and lighttpd --version, however the version outputed was 1.4.45 stil

Comment: i don't see a `service lighttpd restart` in the instructions. (most likely the `service restart` will restart `/usr/sbin/lighttpd` wheras your `make install` will have installed to `/usr/local/sbin/`)

Comment: so how can I avoid making an install in the wrong directory, then?

Comment: `./configure --help` is your friend. however, the real issue is that you are trying to hijack the infrastructure of your Debian package with your self-compiled binary. you should not do that. Start with uninstalling the `lighttpd` Debian package.

Answer (score 0):

You can build the latest lighttpd release as a Debian package for older Debian systems by using Debian `dpkg-buildpackage`

```
release=$(curl -s https://download.lighttpd.net/lighttpd/releases-1.4.x/latest.txt)
release=${release#*-}
wget https://download.lighttpd.net/lighttpd/releases-1.4.x/lighttpd-$release.tar.xz
mv lighttpd-$release.tar.xz lighttpd_$release.orig.tar.xz
git clone https://salsa.debian.org/debian/lighttpd.git
cd lighttpd/
dpkg-buildpackage -uc -us
cd ..
ls lighttpd*_$release*.deb
# dpkg -i ...
```

(The above assumes that debian/changelog matches the latest lighttpd release.  Change $release as appropriate.)